# how to JOIN table variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
    DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(max));
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1, 'A');
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (3, 'C');

    DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(max));
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (1, 'X');
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (2, 'Y');
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (3, 'Z');

    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM @T1 t1
    JOIN @T2 t2;
```

Getting a syntax error near the last ';'. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing on condition clause to join the tables

Comment: isn't condition optional? I need all rows, full cartesian product

Comment: If you need Cartesian product you can use cross join or another way to write is select t1.id , t2.name .. From table t1, table t2

Comment: @radar: this style is **discouraged** since the **ANSI SQL-92** standard - more than **20 years** ago! You should use the **proper** ANSI `CROSS JOIN` syntax instead!

Answer (score 2):

```
JOIN @T2 t2 ON t1.SomeColumn = t2.SomeColumn
```

To do a cross join use the `CROSS JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(max));
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (1, 'A');
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES (3, 'C');

    DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Id int, Name varchar(max));
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (1, 'X');
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (2, 'Y');
    INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES (3, 'Z');

    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM @T1 t1
    JOIN @T2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```